# Black bar on top of the website - only on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I noticed a strange black bar on top of my website which make it really difficult to navigate as it covers my menu button. It only appears when using Firefox browser, on every other browser everything is fine.

I tried to work with css styles of top elements but nothing seems to work properly. Can anyone help?

The site is: http://sabipol.pl/kontakt

And here are the screenshots of the problem:

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Opera:

[image: Opera]

Thanks for help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [mcve].

Comment: I think the question is pretty self explanatory... He's asking how to remove the black bar found in FireFox only. It's just a wording problem.

Comment: @IyadOkal If you read this, [ask], you'll hopefully understand how this question does not follow SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change margin from top to 0px in style.css line no:- 1980
.main-container .row-container .row-parent .single-internal-gutter .uncont > * { margin-top: 0px; }

please see screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCDol.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

Try using this in your css file:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

The reason the black bar exists is because different browsers use different default stylesheets.
Some people recommend a reset stylesheet such as [Eric Meyer's Reset Reloaded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/). These allow for your style to be universal on all browsers.